# Query to select record

Tags: mysql

table name medcn_recrd

```
Name   Qty   Id 
a       12   asc
a       0    asdc
b       0    asfg
c       12   ascd
c       15   acs
```

Query to select  Select id  where  name has qty =0 and total qty of name > 0
In above example asdc is selected id .

Comment: You've written half of the query in your description. Is this homework? What do you mean by "Total qty of name > 0"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about something like

```
SELECT  *
FROM    TABLE t
WHERE   Qty = 0
AND     EXISTS  (
                    SELECT  Name
                    FROM    TABLE t1
                    WHERE   t1.Name = t.Name
                    GROUP BY Name
                    HAVING SUM(Qty) > 0
                )
```

Comment: table name is medcn_recrd , what does t and t1 means in above example .

Comment: t and t1 are used as aliases for the table, so that if you have the same table multiple times in a query, it knows which table you are referring to.

Comment: done . can i use above query as DELETE
FROM    medcn_recrd t
WHERE   Qty = 0
AND     EXISTS  (
                    SELECT  Name
                    FROM    medcn_recrd t1
                    WHERE   t1.Name = t.Name
                    GROUP BY Name
                    HAVING SUM(Qty) > 0
                )

Answer (score 0):

I'll assume this is the part that's tripping you up:

```
SELECT t.Id
FROM theTable t
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT Name
    FROM theTable
    GROUP BY Name
    HAVING SUM(Qty)>0
) sumN ON t.Name = sumN.Name
WHERE t.Qty = 0
```

Comment: you try above query once it will return one id and  null .

Comment: I edited this to write the whole query out. It's almost exactly the same as @astander's answer below, just uses a JOIN instead of EXISTS so it ought to work